# Trac ticket does not get updated via SVN hooks

Tags: svn, trac

I have a Trac and SVN setup done on my server. I have integrated SVN-Trac using post commit hook and post-revprop-change hook. itsWhen I perform a commit, **I can see the timeline on trac getting updated but the corresponding ticket does not get updated with any comments or change  state**. I have tried looking around on google as well as stackoverflow for such issues but then almost all of them had permission issues on linux/unix environments which most likely is not my case. Apparently I do not have any permission issues in my windows environment as I am running trac and svn using my login.

Please find the setup details mentioned below:

**Server OS : Windows 2008 R2**

**- Wandisco SVN server installed using :WANdiscoSubversion_1.7.8-2.exe**

**- Python 2.7.5 (32 bit)**

**- Trac 1.0.1**

I need to have SVN-Trac integrated so that the SVN commits update trac ticket status and comments with the traclink.

To achieve this, I have setup post commit hooks in SVN as mentioned in the Trac documentation at :http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync and http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater.

I have done the following changes :

1. **Enabled the commit ticket updater** via the trac web interface -> admin -> plugins.
2. As per the documentation for CommitTicketUpdater on trac as mentioned above, I've added the   following lines additionally in trac.ini present under trac_env/conf/trac.ini at the [components] section
   tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketreferencemacro = enabled 
   tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketupdater = enabled
3. **Configured commit updater plugin** by adding the following to the [ticket] section of the trac.ini file

   [ticket]
   commit_ticket_update_envelope = []

   commit_ticket_update_commands.close = close closed closes fix fixed fixes

   commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = addresses re references refs see

   commit_ticket_update_check_perms = true

   commit_ticket_update_notify = true

I have also **created post-commit.bat and post-revprop-change.bat** and added it to the hooks folder in my svn repository. Please find the script code below :

post-commit.bat

```
@echo off
::
:: Trac-SVN post commit hook for explicit synchronisation
::

setlocal

set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2

C:\Python27\Scripts\trac-admin.exe C:\apps\new changeset added "%REPOS%" "%REV%"
```

post-revprop-change.bat

```
@echo off
::
:: Trac-SVN post revprop change hook
::

setlocal

set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2

C:\Python27\Scripts\trac-admin.exe C:\apps\new changeset modified "%REPOS%" "%REV%"
```

I have also tried checking trac.log (set at Debug level) but there is nothing relevant logged in there.

I have also printed the values from the post commit hook and they seem to be fine.

Can anyone please help me fix the above mentioned issue ?

Thanks !

Regards

Sowmya Dass

Comment: Ok. I am not even able to see the failure message being logged for me to be able to debug it further. Any clues ?

Comment: I tried removing settings mentioned in step 3 as suggested but it dint work.

Comment: Apparently it started working fine after I fixed up the Trac Permissions. I granted Ticket admin permissions to anonymous users and it started working just fine. When we run the trac-admin command from the post commit hook, we need to ensure that the user has permissions granted to modify the ticket as well. How do you manage the Trac permissions in your setup ?

Comment: If you don't care about the permission checks you can also use `[trac] commit_ticket_update_check_perms = false`, but see my [reply](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/trac-users/7yxg8hB9bRs/LleWSN8EFVkJ) on trac-users mailing list for more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

The user who is used for calling the commit hook should get the necessary permissions (likely TICKET_...).

If you don't care about the permission checks you can also use `[trac] commit_ticket_update_check_perms = false` (as RjOllos already commented above).